# Reference request: automorphism of abelian $p$-groups of rank 2

Tags: finite-groups

There is a result saying that if $P$ is an abelian $p$-group of rank $2$ then $$|Aut(P)|=(p-1)^kp^j(p+1)^r,$$
for some $k,j,r$ which depend on the order of $P$.

Moreover, if $P=C_{p^t}\times C_{p^s}$ for $t\neq s$ then $r=0$ in the above equation.

However, I didn't find any reference to these facts.

Comment: Where did you see these results stated? Have you looked in the list of references?

Comment: It was told to me as a known folklore. The prof. that told it to me didn't know the origin and thats why I am asking here..

Comment: Given the structure theorem for abelian groups, it should not be too hard to count automorphisms by tracking where one sends generators of the cyclic factors of P. This seems to me like it should be a straightforward exercise

Answer (score 0):

Yemon Choi is right to say that for rank two groups this is essentially an exercise. However, a somewhat indirect (and possibly more difficult) approach seems to be instructive here:

Suppose $P$ is a finite abelian $p$-group. Let $P[p] = \{ x\in P \mid px = 0\}$. Then every automorphism $g$ of $P$ restricts to an automorphism $\bar g$ of $P[p]$. Define the *height* $h(x)$ of $x\in P$ as the largest integer $h$ such that $x = p^h y$ for some $y\in P$. The automorphism $\bar g$ is clearly height preserving. It turns out that every height-preserving automorphism of $P[p]$ extends to an automorphism of $P$ (see I. Kaplansky, Infinite Abelian Groups, Academic Press, New York, 1970., page 30). Thus we have an exact sequence:
$$
1 \to N \to \mathrm{Aut}(P) \to \mathrm{Aut}_h(P[p]) \to 1,
$$
where $\mathrm{Aut}_h(P[p])$ denotes the group of height-preserving automorphisms of $P[p]$. Furthermore, $N$ is a $p$-group. Thus your question for general abelian $p$-groups actually becomes a question about the cardinality of a subgroup of $GL(n,p)$ which preserves a flag of subspaces, namely the flag whose subspaces are elements of height greater than or equal to a given integer (a parabolic subgroup).